# Magento rest api url to retrieve products from specific websites

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

My setup looks like this

- Default -> Main Store -> MainStoreView
- Website1 -> Store 1 -> StoreView1 
            Store 2 -> StoreView2

Now I want to know how to retrieve products only from Website1->Store1 or Website1->Store2. I thought of using normal url like www.mysite.com/api/rest/products/ and filter the products by storeId, but the problem is I am not getting any products from Website1. I am getting products only from default website.

Can anyone give any insight into why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest::_retrieveCollection()`:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$store = $this->_getStore();
//[...]
$collection->addStoreFilter($store->getId())
```

So, the collection takes into consideration a store view filter. Let's dig deepr in `_getStore()` method:

`Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::_getStore()`:

```
protected function _getStore()
    {
        $store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        try {
            if ($this->getUserType() != Mage_Api2_Model_Auth_User_Admin::USER_TYPE) {
                // customer or guest role
                if (!$store) {
                    $store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView();
                } else {
                    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($store);
                }
            } else {
                // admin role
                if (is_null($store)) {
                    $store = Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;
                }
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore($store);
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception $e) {
            // store does not exist
            $this->_critical('Requested store is invalid', Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return $store;
    }
```

Based on this, I believe you can specify: `your_request_url?param...&store=STORE_ID`

Comment: Thanks Florinel that is exactly what i was looking for :).